# UnobtrusiveValidationMode not works on client side?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, client-side, .net-4.5, unobtrusive-validation

I migrated recently to the VS 2012 and .NET 4.5 and I'm studying this UnobtrusiveValidationMode.

I configured my Global.asax setting the ScriptResourceMapping for my jquery file and I added the ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode in my WebConfig setting the value as "WebForms".

The validation works on server side but not works on client side.

This new approach don't validates on the client side?